# Why does $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose i} {m+1 \choose i+1} = \frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

For context, I was trying to find in how many differnt ways one could join two lists of length m and n whilst preserving their internal order. 
So, for example, a list of length 1 $\langle 1 \rangle$ and a list of length 4 $\langle2, 3, 4, 5\rangle$ can be combined in five possible ways
$\langle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\rangle, $
$\langle 2, 1, 3, 4, 5\rangle, $
$\langle 2, 3, 1, 4, 5\rangle,$
$\langle 2, 3, 4, 1, 5\rangle, $
$\langle 2, 3, 4, 5, 1\rangle $

And two lists of length 2 $\langle 1,2\rangle$ en $\langle 3,4\rangle$  could be joined in 6 ways.
$\langle 1,2,3,4\rangle,$
$\langle 1,3,2,4\rangle,$
$\langle 1,3,4,2\rangle,$
$\langle 3,4,1,2\rangle,$
$\langle 3,1,4,2\rangle,$
$\langle 3,1,2,4\rangle $

For this I came with the equation* 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose i} {m+1 \choose i+1}$$
Which when plugged into WolframAlpha gives $$\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$$

And for all the my test cases, these two do indeed give the same result.
So, my question is, what is it that makes these two equations be equivalent? I am supposing it has something to do with turning ${n \choose k}$ into $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ but I wouldn't know how to continue due to the summation sign.

*'Proof' of the formula: I make $i$ cuts in the list of length n so as to divide it into $i+1$ pieces. The number of different ways I could make such a cut is ${n-1 \choose i}$. I then insert these pieces into the list of length m this can be done in ${m+1 \choose i+1}$ ways. So when making $i$ cuts I can join the strings in  ${n-1 \choose i} {m+1 \choose i+1}$ ways. I can make up to $n-1$ cuts into the list so we should sum the number of combinations for every possible number of cuts resulting in $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose i} {m+1 \choose i+1}$

Comment: Double-counting: In the end, you always finish with a list long $m+n$ that contains all the elements of list 1 and 2, each of them are sorted according to their original list. In how many ways you can obtain that?

Comment: @Exodd ah, thank you... it really is quite obvious if you put it that way.

Comment: Check this  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3673007/626107

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a combinatorial argument, prove that $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} {n \choose k-1}} = {2n \choose n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672885/using-a-combinatorial-argument-prove-that-displaystyle-sum-k-1n-n-cho)